# How do I fix my neomuttrc syntax?

Tags: mutt, notmuch

I've had Neomutt setup and working great for a while now but at some point I started seeing an error on launch that I'd like to finally fix. The error says:

```
Error in /home/amanda/.config/neomutt/neomuttrc, line 23: 
Binding '\\' will alias '\'  Before, try: 'bind pager \ noop'  https://neomutt.org/guide/configuration.html#bind-warnings
Warning in /home/amanda/.config/neomutt/neomuttrc, line 24: 
source: errors in /home/amanda/.config/neomutt/neomuttrc
```

My goal is to have `\\` open a notmuch query to search my whole mail directory, while `/` just searches the list or query that is open (so if I'm looking at INBOX, `/` will open a prompt to search my INBOX and `\\` will open a prompt to search all mail.

The error suggests adding `bind pager \ noop` but line 23 says exactly that.

What is the right way to set my `neomuttrc` so that `\\` opens a query prompt?

My complete `neomuttrc` file in case there's something else I'm missing:

```
source ~/.config/neomutt/pass.sh|

set smtp_url = "smtp://myself@example.com@mail.example.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = $my_pass
set ssl_force_tls = yes

set from = "myself@velociraptor.info"
set realname = "Myself"

set signature = "~/.config/neomutt/signature"
set status_format = "%n new | %M in %f [%v]."
set xterm_set_titles = yes

# notmuch
set nm_default_uri="notmuch:///home/myself/Mail" # path to the maildir
set spoolfile = ~/Mail/INBOX
set record = ~/Mail/INBOX.Sent
set postponed = ~/Mail/INBOX.Drafts
set mbox_type = Maildir
set folder = ~/Mail/

# notmuch bindings
bind pager \ noop
macro index,pager \\\\ "<vfolder-from-query>"              # looks up a hand made query
macro index A "<modify-labels>+archive -unread -inbox\\n"        # tag as Archived
macro index I "<modify-labels>-inbox -unread\\n"                 # removed from inbox
macro index S "<modify-labels-then-hide>-inbox -unread +junk\\n" # tag as Junk mail
macro index + "<modify-labels>+*\\n<sync-mailbox>"               # tag as starred
macro index - "<modify-labels>-*\\n<sync-mailbox>"               # tag as unstarred

# macro pager ` <edit-label>

# ctrl u searches for URLs
macro pager \cu |urlview\n

# Remap bounce-message function to “B”
bind index B bounce-message


# show the year via http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/mutt/manual-6.html#index_format
set index_format = "%4C %Z %{%b %d %Y} %-15.15L (%?l?%4l&%4c?) %s"

## Save Hooks
save-hook '~s [Rr]eceipt' =INBOX.receipts
save-hook '~s order\ confirmation' =INBOX.receipts
save-hook '~s authorized\ a\ payment' =INBOX.receipts
save-hook '~e Venmo' =INBOX.receipts
save-hook .         =INBOX.Archives.%[%Y]
## Addressing
macro pager,index a "<pipe-message>khard add-email<return>" "add the sender address to khard"

set query_command= "khard email --parsable %s"
bind editor <Tab> complete-query
bind editor ^T    complete


set mailcap_path = ~/.config/mailcap
set print_command="/home/amanda/.config/neomutt/print_unicode.sh"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neomutt uses backslash `\` as an escape character in configuration file. You need to escape it to get literal backslash. But you already know that based on Your config file.

```
bind   index,pager \\     noop
bind   index,pager \\\\   vfolder-from-query
```

You can also use `unbind` command instead of binding the noop function.

```
unbind index,pager \\
bind   index,pager \\\\   vfolder-from-query
```

---

I would also suggest to use `bind` instead of a `macro` if there's no special reason for it. With `bind` you can bind only single function to the key. There might be one handy usecase if you want all searches to exclude some tags:

```
unbind index,pager \\
macro index,pager \\\\   "<vfolder-from-query>NOT tag:newsletters AND "
```

Pressing <kbd>\</kbd> will execute `vfolder-from-query` with prefilled `NOT tag:newsletters AND`  and stay in the command prompt waiting for You to add additional search query parameters.